# Android Retrofit Get Query encoded

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm trying to use simple get request with retrofit, but i've problem with parameters name, characters "[" and "]" are not encoded.

```
@Headers("Accept: application/vnd.api+json")
@GET("v2/point_of_sales/{point_of_sales}/books")
fun retrievesBooks(@Path("point_of_sales", encoded = true) pointOfSales: String,
                        @Query("include", encoded = true) include: String,
                        @Query("fields[category]", encoded = true) fieldsCategory: String,
                        @Query("fields[title]", encoded = true) fieldsTitle: String, @Query("fields[version]", encoded = true) fieldsVersion: String): Call<String>
```

If i replace parameters name like fields%5Btitle%5D it's working.
How can i encode my url ?

Thanks

Comment: um, set `encoded = false` (or omit the parameter, since it has that default value)? That will say that the query is not already encoded.

Comment: encoded false not working and there is not default value =( with HttpLogInterceptor request has "[" and "]", i need @FormUrlEncoded like post request i think or something like that.